# How to save streaming video in iOS?

Tags: ios, save, video-streaming, avplayer

How to save a streaming video locally?

I am using the below code using AVPlayer for playing a m3u8 file.

```
private func playVideo3() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://filenaname.m3u8") else {
        return
    }

    // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
    let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = view3.bounds
    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    view3.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.play()
}
```

I need to save the streaming video into PhotoLibrary when pressing on the stop button(custom Button).

Answer (score 0):

you can try with NSURLProtocol Subclassing and save the video.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift

Comment: is it possible to save the  AVPlayer streaming video ?

Comment: AVPlayer doesn't provide method for saving video.